# How did the system($command) call return a 0 exit code even though the command was still running?

Tags: linux, perl, operating-system, child-process, sigterm

The following perl code was running through a Python script.

```
my $pid = fork;
my @pids;
if ($pid) { 
    push(@pids, $pid);
    $return_code = system($command);
}
foreach my $pid (@pids) {
    waitpid($pid, 0);
}

$return_code = $return_code >> 8;
return $return_code;
```

This $return_code was 0 even though the $command ran for next 5 minutes.

This happened only once. I could not reproduce this later. Could anyone identify what possibly caused this issue? The $command will invoke several perl threads.

Answer (score 2):

That `system` runs in a parent process<sup>†</sup> after the `fork`, while the child process falls through right away.  Since the `@pids` is written to *in one of the processes* (the parent) the other one (the child) doesn't see this change to a parent's variable; its own `@pids` stays as it was before the `if` split the processes.<sup>‡</sup>  Thus since *its* `@pids` is empty the child process just passes over that loop.

Then, in that child process that fell through and went over the empty loop, the right-shift (`>>`) is done on an undefined value (`$return_code` has not been assigned yet) -- *for what you'd get a warning if you had `use warnings;` on* -- and the result of that is converted to `0`, which is then assigned. And then that is returned.

So that zero is bogus, meaningless.

Do `push @pids, $pid` *before* the `if` condition, right after `fork`.

Also, you need to exit one of these processes -- commonly the one inside the `if` condition -- or you'll have *two* processes executing all code that follows.

Another option is to add an `else` branch for the child, in which the child process exits.  Then all is well again since the parent will eventually get to its `@pids` list.

---

<sup>†</sup>  It is common to select branches by

```
if ($pid == 0) {  # child process enters this branch, parent does not
    ...
}
# parent process drops right here, since its pid is not `0`
```

In this question that is reversed, testing for true `$pid` -- and so here *the parent process* enters the branch and the child drops right below it.  That's OK as well of course and the discussion applies.

---

<sup>‡</sup>  As soon as a variable is written to the processes get their own copies.

But let's imagine that the other process (child) sees that change in `@pids` (made in the parent). There would still be a problem -- there would be a race condition, as the child may well get to the loop over `@pids` *before* the `push @pids, $pid` in the parent (inside the `if` branch) happens.

Comment: In other words, do `push @pids, $pid` _before_ entering the child process, right after `fork`.  That's where it belongs anyway

Comment: The command ran for several minutes before the `$return_code`  and several minutes after. Also we are doing `push @pids, $pid` right after fork.

Comment: "_we are doing push `@pids, $pid` right after fork_"  -- no, you are not; it's inside the child process.  In the meanwhile the parent drops below and has every chance of beating that.  I don't know what ran for how long but you have a bug there, a race condition. Move `push` _before_ entering the child process.  See the last sentence in my answer

Comment: I could not get understand it.  `my $pid = fork;
my @pids;
if ($pid) { 
    push(@pids, $pid);
}` , will the if condition go into a child process ?

Comment: The `if ($pid == 0) { ... }` is what the child process enters.  You reversed it sort of, but it still works: `if ($pid) { }` branch is entered by the parent _but not by the child_ (which has pid of 0), so the child just skips it and immediately gets to the loop over `@pids`

Comment: So you want `my @pids;  my $pid = fork // die "can't fork: $!";  push @pids, $pid; if ($pid) { .... }`.  I assume you `fork` more than one process, thus a separate declaration of `@pids`.  (If it were just one you wouldn't need an array `@pids`)

Comment: added an additional condition for child process. Please refer to the code in the question.

Comment: @tourist "_added an additional condition for child process_"  -- well, but that fixes the problem.  Then there is no question to ask.  I reverted that change, to the question meaningful.  change it back if you wish -- or let me know that you want that and I'll do it -- and I won't touch it again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254702/discussion-between-tourist-and-zdim).

Comment: @tourist And added comments to our "chat" (I think that one _doesn't_ get notified of that so I'm saying it here)

Comment: @tourist Updated the answer again, to summarize that last comment from the chat.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you're calling perl from python but I am assuming you're using subprocess module

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen("call perl script",  stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
output = process.communicate()
print(output)
```